# Create classes with interfaces. Then iterate though it in codebehind

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, interface, iterator

I have a question about classes with including interfaces. I have about 12 classes with all the same interface in it. Now, I need to list all classes. In the feature there could be 1000 new classed to create. But because they are responsible for devices some times some classes are obsolete.

Ok. No problem to list all classes by using

```
dim ClassList as new List(Of MyInterface)
ClassList.Add(New MyFirstItem())
ClassList.Add(New MySecondItem())
ClassList.Add(New MyThirdItem())
ClassList.Add(New ...)
```

then

```
For each item as MyInterface in ClassList
   'Print info
next
```

that what I am doing NOW.

**I want to ask if it is possible tell visual studio or my application that I have one solution folder with all classes written in and to add automatically these items to the list. Or do it like plugins. I want to avoid the lines above. And I want to avoid creating a complete new project just for some lines of code in each class.**

```
ClassList.Add(New ...) 'would like to avoid this to do manually
```

just to create an instance and dispose it immediately again for writing the class information on screen.

Hope I could explain my question

Regards

Comment: So you are wanting to output a list of class names?

Comment: I want to walk through all classes. But I want to ask if you have any cool idea to add the classnames automatically in codebhind (by script) or to do it by application or plugin methodes. As far I know, you can not instance a "application\subfolder\" with all classes in it. But I think that is what it will make very easy. To include all classes in my "application\subfolder\" where the 1000 classes are stored in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your classes are in their own files named their class name in the directory you could do a little app that would output your lines to a text file like this:

```
String[] Files= Directory.GetFiles("PATH", "*.cs");                
foreach (String file in Files)
{
    WriteLine("ClassList.Add(new " + file.Replace(".cs", "") + ");");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chad. Is there any chance to do this with Microsoft tools like snippets or something like that? Because I like your answer. But perhaps I could learn something about VS tools with similar effect. Regards